How to configure Azure Application Insight for a Java Spring Boot in a Pod in Azure AKS
I have a SpringBoot app and this is running in a POD in AKS. I configured an Application Insights agent. For me all looks good. But i can not see in Application Insights the data that i would expect. eg the HeapSpace. Maybe I am just too stupid to find the info.
Quesiton: I my setup so ok?
SpringBoot 3.3.3
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.4</version>
</dependency>

I configured the following Enviromant Variables for my Pod
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_AUTHENTICATION_STRING
When the Pod starts up I see the following output for the Agent:
  WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (/tmp/otel-agent3340747174827410017/agent.jar)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
  │ WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
  │ WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
  │ WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
  │ OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended                                                                                                                                                                                     │
  │ 2024-09-19 09:18:27.414Z INFO  c.m.a.a.i.c.ConfigurationBuilder - Some telemetry may be sampled out because a default sampling configuration was added in version 3.4.0 to reduce the default billing cost. You can set the sampling configuration explicitly: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/ja │
  │ 2024-09-19 09:18:29.791Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Application Insights Java Agent 3.5.4 started successfully (PID 1, JVM running for 3.66 s)                                                                                                                                                             │
  │ 2024-09-19 09:18:29.797Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Java version: 21.0.4, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, home: /opt/java/openjdk                                                                                                                                                                                │
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
  │   .   ____          _            __ _ _                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
  │  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
  │ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
  │  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
  │   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
  │  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
  │  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.3)

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


To configure Application Insights for your Spring Boot app deployed inside AKS
Create an Application Insights
az monitor app-insights component create --app springboot-appinsights --location eastus --resource-group arkorg --kind web --application-type java


Retrieve the Connection String
az monitor app-insights component show --app springboot-appinsights --resource-group arkorg --query connectionString --output tsv


Update your pom.xml accordingly. Push the Spring Boot Docker Image to your Azure Container Registry and use that same inside your aks deployment and service yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
  labels:
    app: springboot-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: springboot-app
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/springboot-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
          value: "<Your-Application-Insights-Connection-String>"
        - name: APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_JVM_METRICS
          value: "true"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret


service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: springboot-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080






Now go to your application insights and under live metrics you can monitor your spring boot app deployed inside your aks


Azure Application Insights is now configured for your Spring Boot application running in the AKS pod. From Live Metrics Stream, you can see the request rate is being tracked, and you can see successful (200 OK) and failed (404) HTTP requests in the telemetry. The Dependency Call Rate and Dependency Call Duration are also being monitored, meaning that Application Insights is capturing outgoing calls from your application.
You can even verify the same inside the aks cluster as well-


i was missing the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_JVM_METRICS.
